# How to read .csv file in that located in Azure?

Tags: azure, csv, azure-storage

My apologies for asking this basic question. I'm very new in Azure environment.

I have stored log files in Azure portal as .csv
I want to view this .csv file without download it.
Azure already give the URL link for this file. But it is unable to view

This is the link that provides by Azure for my .csv file:

```
https://xxxxxx.xfile.xcore.windows.net/cctvfeedfs/log/testcsv.csv
```

Fyi, I do have SAS signature, this SAS signature when I combine with the URL its will download the .csv file. Example like this:

```
https://xxxxxx.xfile.xcore.windows.net/cctvfeedfs/log/testcsv.csv?sv=2017-11-09&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2099-10-04T09:06:59Z&st=2018-10-04T01:06:59Z&spr=https&sig=%2Fb%2BrssXtUP5V%2F9%2BSXzpSauyugpG%2BvXOfn9GqLfdf1EOUE%3D
```

But actually I don't want to download but just want to view it.
It is have any possible way to do so I can view the content in .csv without download it?

Please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi sir, Thank you for your suggestion sir. But in my case, I should not change the content type of file. Because this log file is created by another developer to submit log to this .csv file. So by changing the content-type, i wonder it will cause any issue for the current system to submit log to that .csv file.

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do to view the content online without download it?

If your container is not public,the url can't be viewed the content of the file directly, otherwise there would be no any security for your files.

So please refer to the offical documents [`Secure access to an application's data in the cloud`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-secure-access-application) and [`Using shared access signatures (SAS)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json). Then, we need to generate a blob url with SAS signature for accessing.

Here is the sample java code to generate a blob url with SAS signature.

```
SharedKeyCredentials credentials = new SharedKeyCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
ServiceSASSignatureValues values = new ServiceSASSignatureValues()
                .withProtocol(SASProtocol.HTTPS_ONLY) // Users MUST use HTTPS (not HTTP).
                .withExpiryTime(OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(2)) // 2 days before expiration.
                .withContainerName(containerName)
                .withBlobName(blobName);
BlobSASPermission permission = new BlobSASPermission()
                .withRead(true)
                .withAdd(true)
                .withWrite(true);
values.withPermissions(permission.toString());
SASQueryParameters serviceParams = values.generateSASQueryParameters(credentials);
String sasSign = serviceParams.encode();
String blobUrlWithSAS = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s%s",
                accountName, containerName, blobName, sasSign);
```

You also can add the SAS signature at the end of the string of `blob.toURL()`.

```
String blobUrlWithSAS = blob.toString()+sasSign;
```

About SAS Signature, you can refer to these sample codes in [`ServiceSASSignatureValues Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.servicesassignaturevalues?view=azure-java-stable) and [`AccountSASSignatureValues Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.accountsassignaturevalues?view=azure-java-stable).

---

You could check the ContentType with your csv file in Azure Storage Explorer Tool.

[image]

If you change the format of it to text/plain,

[image]

then it could show the content directly in the browser. 
[image]

BTW,you could set the content type when you upload the file.(Please see this SO case :[Uploading blockblob and setting contenttype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621664/uploading-blockblob-and-setting-contenttype/24622986))

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for your answer. Yes, I do have SAS signature sir. But it will download the .csv file when I combine with the file URL. I prefer not to download it but just wanna to view it. Please help