# Setting content type with BlobContainerClient.UploadBlobAsync()

Tags: c#, azure

These two posts looked promising:

[How upload blob in Azure Blob Storage with specified ContentType with .NET v12 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59945376/how-upload-blob-in-azure-blob-storage-with-specified-contenttype-with-net-v12-s)

[Uploading blockblob and setting contenttype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621664/uploading-blockblob-and-setting-contenttype)

But in both, they are using different libraries. (Why are there so many?) As mandated by powers out of my control, we are using [BlobContainerClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-dotnet). And within that class, we are using the [UploadBlobAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.uploadblobasync?view=azure-dotnet) method.

```
public async Task<string> UploadAsync(string fileName, byte[] file, string containerName)
{
    ...
    BlobContainerClient container = await createContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName);
    using Stream stream = file.ToStream();
    var result = await container.UploadBlobAsync(fileName, stream);  // <-- does the upload.
    ...
}
```

By default, the type is set to `application/octet-stream`. How can I override this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59945376/how-upload-blob-in-azure-blob-storage-with-specified-contenttype-with-net-v12-s is the correct answer for you. The other answer is for the older SDK.

Comment: @GauravMantri, thanks. You are correct. I just didn't dig far enough.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. There are two ways you can upload a file to blob storage.

The first is how I was doing it, which was by bypassing the creation of the `BlobClient`.  See the OP for an example.

The second looks like this:

```
public async Task<string> UploadAsync(string fileName, byte[] file, string containerName)
{
    ...
    BlobContainerClient container = await createContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName);
    BlobClient blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(fileName);
    using Stream stream = file.ToStream();
    var result = await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "text/plain" });
    ...
}
```

Comment: @TruthSeeker, it's just a method that does exactly what it says. Doesn't really come into play for this question.

Comment: If upgrading to Azure.Storage:  /*using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;*/ blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = mimetype;  await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
/*using Azure.Storage;*/ await blockBlob.UploadAsync(fileStream, new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = mimetype });